# Why does my WorkbookView sequence keep returning "null" value with OpenXml?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, excel, openxml

I have created a download button in C#/asp.net, which takes a GridView, converts it to a data table, and then stores it into a .xlsx file. What I want to do after is be able to change the active tab of the spreadsheet I created.

Here is the code below:

```
 protected void downloadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(Server.MapPath("~/Downloads/TestSheet.xlsx"), DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheet.AddWorkbookPart();
            workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

            //Fine up to this point

            spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new Sheets();

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            //Converts GridView into Data Table **
            for (int i = 0; i < gvEmployee.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
            {

                table.Columns.Add(gvEmployee.HeaderRow.Cells[i + 1].Text);
            }
            // fill rows     
            for (int i = 0; i < gvEmployee.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
                for (int j = 0; j < gvEmployee.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    dr[j] = gvEmployee.Rows[i].Cells[j + 1].Text;
                }
                table.Rows.Add(dr);

            }

            var sheetPart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            var sheetData = new SheetData();
            sheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetData);

            Sheets sheets = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
            string relationshipId = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);

            uint sheetId = 1;
            if (sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Count() > 0)
            {
                sheetId = sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
            }

            Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = "TestSheet" };
            sheets.Append(sheet);

            Row headerRow = new Row();
            List<String> columns = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {

                columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

                Cell cell = new Cell();
                cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                cell.CellValue = new CellValue(column.ColumnName);
                headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
            }


            sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);
            foreach (DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
            {
                Row newRow = new Row();
                foreach (String col in columns)
                {
                    Cell cell = new Cell();
                    cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString()); //
                    newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                }

                sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
            }


            Sheet sheet2 = new Sheet() { Id = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart), SheetId = 2, Name = "AdditionalSheet" };
            sheets.Append(sheet2);

            var sheetIndex = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().ToList().IndexOf(sheet2);
            WorkbookView workbookView = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<WorkbookView>().FirstOrDefault(); //new WorkbookView();
            workbookView.ActiveTab = Convert.ToUInt32(sheetIndex);

            workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
            spreadSheet.Close();

        }
    }
```

When I try to run this code, it throws an error on the "workbookView.ActiveTab" at the last few lines stating

**System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'**

**workbookView was null.**

Any ideas as to why its doing this?

Comment: I think you are creating a new workbook instead of putting the sheet into an existing workbook.

Comment: Okay, I just tried closing the spreadsheet and reopening it with another "using statement", and attempted to choose the active tab in that statement, but it still returns a null value. Any other tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you getting one or two workbooks opened?

Comment: I am only getting one workbook named TestSheet.xlsx as it's named in the path. When I comment out the section that attempts to choose an active tab, it saves the workbook successfully to server with both "TestSheet" and "AdditionalSheet", but when I uncomment that section it says "workbookView is null".

Comment: Put a break point where the error is occurring and then check excel application that is open and verify there is only one workbook opened.by clicking on the excel icon on the taskbar.

Comment: Yes there is only one workbook opened

Comment: Why does the workbookView not look like line above?  var workbookView = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().FirstOrDefault(); //new WorkbookView();

Comment: When I do that, I get the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet' to 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.WorkbookView'

Comment: Try following which uses ChildView : https://codeday.me/en/qa/20190309/15577.html

Comment: Okay, I just tried the use of the if statements and the different WorkbookView statement, but that WorkbookView line returned an error of:                                                 
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook.BookViews.get returned null.

Comment: Try in two steps to see where the issue is occurring.  First get the sheet using my last link.  Make sure it is not null.  Then get the view.

Comment: Okay, I have edited it to use two try/catch statements. It is failing within the first try statement, on the line: **WorkbookView workbookView = workbookPart.Workbook.BookViews.ChildElements.First<WorkbookView>();**. Catch Exception that I am getting is: **System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at DevTest4.EmployeeData.downloadBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DevTestDatabase\EmployeeData.aspx.cs:line 390**

Comment: I'll take a look later.  You have to be careful of not mixing WorkSheet and Sheet.  WorkSheet is a subset of Sheet.  I suspect there is something with the code with the way you are using Sheet and WorkSheet, but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just figured out what was wrong, there was no WorkbookView initialized, as I thought it thought it didn't need to be. But you have to actually make a WorkbookView of your workbook before you can change it. I just needed this one line:

```
            workbookPart.Workbook.Append(new BookViews(new WorkbookView()));
```